# How to pick 3 unique arrays?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, unique

```
var arr = ['1','2','3','4'];
```

How can I pick  3 unique arrays from `arr` ?

I can only pick one by one like..

```
function pick(a){
    var i = Math.floor(Math.random()*a.length);
    return a[i];
}
```

Picked arrays will not be duplicate.

I have no idea to do... Thanks so much :D

**Playground :** http://jsbin.com/ocuhig/1/edit

Comment: will it be possible to modify the source array then http://jsbin.com/ocuhig/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution:

```
var copy = arr.slice();
while (copy.length > 3) {
    copy.splice(~~(Math.random() * copy.length), 1);
}
```

And even more cute solution:

```
var copy = arr.slice().sort(function() {
    return Math.random() - 0.5;
}).slice(0, 3);
```

Comment: Thanks! Look like so easy , What is `~~` ?

Comment: @l2aelba This is a shortcut for `Math.floor`.

Comment: Yep, this should be faster than my answer!

Comment: VisioN: I know what you mean by a shortcut, but @l2aelba may not. It's not a  shortcut in the sense that it maps directly to the `.floor()` method. Rather in this particular scenario, it's a shorter way of achieving the same result. In other situations the result can be different.

Comment: @squint Yes, literally you are absolutely right. `~~` is a trick to truncate the fractional part.

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * Returns a random integer between min and max
 */
function getRandomInt (min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution :

```
var picker = function(a, picked) {
    if ( !picked ) picked = [];
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*a.length);
    if ( picked.indexOf(a[randomNumber]) === -1 ) picked.push(a[randomNumber]);
    if ( picked.length < 3 ) 
       return picker(a, picked);
    else
       return picked;
}
```

Playground : http://jsbin.com/owevuh/1/